# Jenkins vs. custom script

Tags: svn, deployment, jenkins

I'm currently facing a dilemma on how to deploy a PHP application.

Here is how my setup looks like:

- A test server where I also have my SVN repository. I have a post-commit script that exports the trunk to automatically deploy a copy to the test server on each commit.
- A second production server.

The deployment I'm talking about is obviously from the first server to the second.

I'm currently using a script I wrote that looks pretty much like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Removing Old Export."
rm -rf /tmp/app_export

echo "SVN Export."
svn export -q -r HEAD "file:///var/www/svn/app/trunk" /tmp/app_export

echo "Changing permissions"
chown -R apache.apache /tmp/app_export

echo "*** Rsynching to app.com."
rsync -zai --progress --stats --ignore-times --checksum /tmp/app_export/ user@app.com:/var/www/html/app/ --exclude '*.log'
```

But everyone says I should be using Jenkins (or something like that) to deploy my application. What would the pros of this be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If this script meets your needs, then it meets your needs. Jenkins has a vast amount of added features that you can read about on their website, but if you don't need them, then don't bother.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jenkins is designed to support builds, but in fact it's a generic automation framework

Advantages of using Jenkins:

- Can call the same script you're using now to deploy your application
- A Jenkins job can be setup to automatically trigger whenever someone makes a source code repository commit
- Credentials for the deployment can be confined to Jenkins. That way a deployment is either automatically triggered or you can setup user authorization rules controlling who's allowed to run a deployment
- Jenkins acts as a central dashboard, recording when deployments took place.
- Could add some functional tests which are run as "post build" actions in Jenkins.
- ..
- ..

Comment: So it's pretty much how @jiggy put it. I'll keep using my script until I need it. Thanks!